# Overload Resolution between func(const char*) and func(std::string&)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two functions:

```
int func(const std::string& str) { return func(str.c_str()); }
int func(const char* str) { /* ... */ }
```

If I call `func(std::string("abcdef"));` first function (`const std::string&`) call recursively itself, not a `const char*` because type conversion.

I can use *Forward Declaration*:

```
int func(const char* str);
int func(const std::string& str) { return func(str.c_str()); }
int func(const char* str) { /* ... */ }
```

or change functions definitions order:

```
int func(const char* str) { /* ... */ }
int func(const std::string& str) { return func(str.c_str()); }
```

and it works.

But is there another way for *Overload Resolution*?

Comment: I don't understand. You already solved the problem. What else do you want?

Comment: Relevant: [Does the order of overloaded function declaration matter in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56979566/580083)

Comment: Overload resolution: the compiler 1st builds a set of valid functions.  At the time of calling `func(str.c_str());` it has only seen `int func(const std::string& str)` so that single function is the only candidate in the overload set of functions to be resolved.

Comment: Can I "strictly say" to compiler to prevent char* to string conversion?

Comment: if you seperate declaration and definition there is no issue. Why do you want "another way" ?

Comment: @OomphSonar no because constructor (5) is not marked explicit https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: "Can I "strictly say" to compiler to prevent char* to string conversion?" typically a way to do that is by providing an overload for each then the overlaod without conversion is a better match :D

Comment: There are pretty strict rules for how overload resolution is applied.  In in general "the closest fit" wins. E.g. if you have a function accepting one int and a function template that would also accept an int then the int function wins because it is an explicit match. The bad thing is that classes sometimes come with implicit conversions which may result in overloads being found in a surprising way, but those matches are only found after explicit matches are found first (I forgot where in the standard this is specified exactly)

Comment: The only way I've found to exclude implicit type conversions is to make template functions that only accept exact type matches e.g. `template<typename type_t> auto func(const T& string) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::string,type_t>> { ... }` (probably there is a nicer way to do this in C++20)

Comment: @PepjinKramer why not make this an answer? I'm not really sure what OP is looking for, but if I had to guess it would be that

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer Functions signatures must be preserved.

Comment: They are for the compiler still the same. Or do you mean you cannot change the header files? If so then make a new header file with these template functions signature and forward the implementation to the existing one.  Then you can use the explicit type checking in your own code.

Comment: And yes I forgot the int return type in std::enable_if_t ;)

Comment: Problem here s caused by fact that compiler do not see functions declared/defined lower in source code. So declaring function at top (in header) and then defining below is perfectly valid and best solution. No need to do some crazy other stuff.

Comment: Offtopic: I would drop both overloads in favor of `int func(std::string_view str)` and let implicit conversions take over.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude implicit type conversions from overload resolution you should make template functions that only accept exact type matches. (SFINAE) e.g.

```
template<typename type_t> 
auto func(const type_t& string) 
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::string,type_t>,int> 
{ 
}
```

This will resolve to a function returning an int only when std::string and type_t exactly match (without conversions)

Comment: In C++20 this simplifies to `auto func(std::same_as<std::string> auto& string){}`

Comment: @joergbrech Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/MereTcEs3

Comment: Problem in question is just order of declaration and definitions. Your solution adds obsolete complexity and do not fixes the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/zoevc1bYv changing order or adding declarations fixes issue without template hack.

Comment: T is indeed type_t, fixed
@joergbrech thanks that was what I was looking for.